# Building a jQuery slideshow from scratch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build an auto playing slideshow from scratch, both for a site I'm working on and as a learning exercise. As such I want to learn how to do it myself and not resort to using a plugin or one of the many excellent freely available slideshows. Here's what I've got so far: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mandrill/zTdxs/15/

Heres the JS:

```
$("#s1").css("display", "block"); // displays slide one as default on page load
$("#slideshow").click(function () {
    $(".slide").each(function (index) {
        var n = index + 1;
        $("#s" + n).toggle("fade");
        return index;
    });
});
```

It's currently just switching between slide one and all the other slides. How do I get it to cycle through the slides in order in a continuous loop?

Comment: have a search for some tutorials, [there is one here](http://www.crosscode.co.uk/jquery/jquery-carousel-tutorial/) that looks like it could do what you want, if you change the timer to a click event for the rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. My lack of understanding of loops was my downfall. The .each() function is not required. Here's the working JS:

```
$("#s1").css("display","block").addClass("active");
$("#slideshow").click(function(){
    var currentSlide =  $(".active").attr("id"); 
    if ($("#slideshow .slide:last").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".active").toggle("fade").removeClass("active");
        $("#slideshow .slide:first").toggle("fade").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".active").toggle("fade").removeClass("active");
        $("#"+currentSlide).next(".slide").toggle("fade").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

It can be seen in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mandrill/wLTns/6/

Thanks to all for their input :) Next step: making it autoplay and adding a timer...

Comment: I've used the above code with minor edits for the next and previous buttons (only on my local testing page, sorry), and have added a timer: http://jsfiddle.net/mandrill/nuQVJ/8/. Next: pause and play buttons.

Answer (score 1):

As with any piece of code, if you're not sure how to do it (but are looking for a learning experience) then there's no better way of learning that looking at real live code already written. Get the (un-minified) versions of a few slideshows that you find and read the code.

My favourite slideshow plugin is the `cycle` one - there's a light version with fairly readable code: http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.lite.js

To give you a more specific answer to your particular question, you can reset the index back to the start.